# Use multiple WebBrowser tabs for 1 flex Application

Tags: windows, apache-flex, popup, browser

I'm developing a flex application to view charts and statistic data about real-time stock price. The requirement is that 1 user can view multiple windows (or panel, or canvas) of multiple stock symbols at the same time.

I want to have 1 button, when I click at that button, a new panel will be pop up in a new WebBrowser tab. 1 user can open 5 or more panels like that in 5 more webbrowser tab to see 5 different stocks. And all 5 panels must be managed by the main Application. So that the Application can send stock price data to those 5 panels.

After days searching, I still cannot find out a way to do that, please suggest me something?

Thank you a lot,
Henry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the requirement is that you use tabs in a browser, then you've got some fun ahead of you.

Only way I could see this working, is if the main application fired off URL Requests for a secondary app which it then communicated with through a LocalConnection.

There are a couple of easier ways if you relax the requirements a little. Using URL parameters means you could pass the stock you are looking to follow into each new instance of the application without needing LocalConnection.

Of course, you could just have a tabbed interface inside your Flex app, and not require new browser windows at all!

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely not go about this way.
Creating multiple tabs is OK, but not when you need full control and integration over these parts.

I would create floating panels in the same application with a tabbed navigation or something of this sort.

Take a look at this image:
[image]

as you can see, the user is seeing one screen, but he has also 2 tabs (windows) at the bottom which he can expand or collapse.

the context is the same context, it is the same application.